# POST data using RenderMvcController in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have set up a document type in `Umbraco`, and have created a custom controller & model for this document type.

The custom controller inherits from : `RenderMvcController` class and the views inherit the model through `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<com.something.model>`

This all works fine for any HttpGet requests. However as soon as I want to do a form post back to the controller using @using `(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", null,  new { @class = "some-class" }))`

I get the following error message: Could not find a Surface controller route in the RouteTable for controller name SomeController

From all the documentation that I was able to find it always refers to SurfaceControllers when it comes to form posts. Is there a way to change the routing so that it would post to my custom controller, rather then another controller that inherits from the `SurfaceController` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/38662-(v6)-Could-not-find-a-Surface-controller-route-error?p=0,

`SomeController` Needs to inherit from `SurfaceController`, not `RenderMvcController`.

Alternatively, you could create a dedicate route and point it directly to your controller:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
         routes.MapRoute("someController", "some/someAction",
            new { controller = "Some", action = "SomeAction" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

then I got below error.

"Can only use UmbracoPageResult in the context of an Http POST when using a SurfaceController form"

Comment: Are you rendering a page on the front end or back end?

Comment: front end.
I have created Surface Controller.
public class SampleSurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult Sample(int id = 0)
        {
            Category model = new Category();
            var repo = new CategoryRepository();
            model.lstCategory = repo.GetAll();
             
            //return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }
What will return surface controller action?

Comment: Currently I am using both controller for get & post. But I am getting an error when inserting record in database using Umbraco.Core. Error: "No mapping exists from object type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlPublishedContent to a known managed provider native type." on public void Insert(Category category)
{
    _database.Insert(category);
}

Answer (score 5):

If you are going to post the form in this way, you need two controllers. One for the Document Type that inherits from `MvcRenderController` (as you already have) and a second which inherits from the `SurfaceController`.

The surface controller just needs a single POST action that does one of the following things:

```
// e.g. if modelstate is invalid
return CurrentUmbracoPage();

// redirecting back to original page after a successful post
return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage(); 

// Redirecting to another page after a successful post
return RedirectToUmbracoPage(12345)
```

This has been taken from the documentation here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/forms

Strictly speaking the initial document type controller is not necessary in this scenario as it does not play a part in the post of the form.

If you want to post directly to the custom controller then you should not use `Html.BeginUmbracoForm`, you should just post directly to the current URL. The complication here is that it is then a little tricky to bind your model as a parameter of the post action. Your view model will have to inherit from `RenderModel` in the following way:

```
public class BaseModel : RenderModel
{
    public BaseModel() :
      base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent) { }
}
```

Comment: I have tried both controller. RendermvcController for view data on load and Surface controller for post data. Its working individually.
I have also used BaseModel and inherited it in my model.

Still its not working because of RenderModel, its throwing an error occur at BaseModel (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

And is it compulsory to use two controller(RenderMvcController & SurfaceController) for same view(for Insert,Update,Delete,List)?

Comment: No but it gets complicated if you don't. You really need to read the documentation thoroughly as it gives you working examples.

Comment: I have read documentation but I did not get any CURD operation application Because I want all in single page. Can you please give me that link or solution which will solve my confusion.I am very confused with controller.

Comment: Currently I am using both controller for get & post. But I am getting an error when inserting record in database using Umbraco.Core. Error: "No mapping exists from object type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlPublishedContent to a known managed provider native type." on public void Insert(Category category) { _database.Insert(category); }

Comment: Excellent, so you got the posting working. That's good news. If you have another separate problem now, raise another question and don't forget to add your code.

Comment: Thanks and I have created new question on link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565935/getting-error-on-posting-data-in-umbraco)