# Getting error on posting data in Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco7

Currently I am using both controller for get(RenderMvcController) & post(SurfaceController). But I am getting an error when inserting record in database using Umbraco.Core. 
**Error: "No mapping exists from object type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlPublishedContent to a known managed provider native type."**

Model - BaseModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Web;

namespace SampleLogic.Models
{
    public class BaseModel : Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel
    {
        public BaseModel()
        : base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent)
        {}
    }
}
```

Model - Category.cs

```
[TableName("Categories")]
[PrimaryKey("Id", autoIncrement = true)]
public class Category : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Category> lstCategory;

    public Category()
    {
        lstCategory = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

View:Sample.cshtml

```
@using SampleLogic
@using SampleLogic.Models
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "umbLayout.cshtml";
    var repo = new CategoryRepository();
}

@Html.Action("AddCategory", "SampleSurface")
@foreach (var category in repo.GetAll())
{
    <p>
        @category.Name 
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Sample", "Sample", new { id = @category.Id }, null)
        <a href="?id=@category.Id">Edit</a>
    </p>
}
```

Repository: CategoryRepository.cs

```
using SampleLogic.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using umbraco.DataLayer;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Persistence;

namespace SampleLogic
{
    public class CategoryRepository
    {
        private readonly UmbracoDatabase _database;
        public CategoryRepository()
        {
            _database = ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database;
        }

        public List<Category> GetAll()
        {
            return _database.Fetch<Category>("select * from categories");
        }

        public Category GetCategoryById(int id)
        {
            return _database.FirstOrDefault<Category>("select * from categories where Id = " + id);
        }

        public void Insert(Category category)
        {
            _database.Insert(category);
        }

        public void Update(Category category)
        {
            _database.Update(category);
        }

        public void Delete(Category category)
        {
            _database.Delete(category);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller: SampleController.cs

```
using SampleLogic.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace SampleLogic.Controllers
{
    public class SampleController : RenderMvcController
    {
        public ActionResult Sample(int id = 0)
        {
            Category model = new Category();
            var repo = new CategoryRepository();

            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {
                model.Name = repo.GetCategoryById(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])).Name;
            }

            model.lstCategory = repo.GetAll();
            return CurrentTemplate(model);
        }

    }
}
```

Controller: SampleSurfaceController.cs

```
using SampleLogic.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace SampleLogic.Controllers
{
    public class SampleSurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Sample(Category model)
        {
            var repo = new CategoryRepository();
            if (model.Id > 0)
            {
                repo.Update(model);
            }
            else
            {
                repo.Insert(model);
            }
            model.Name = string.Empty;
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult AddCategory(Category model)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {
                var repo = new CategoryRepository();
                model.Name = repo.GetCategoryById(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])).Name;
            }
            //TODO: do some searching (perhaps using Examine) 
            //using the information contained in the custom class QueryParameters

            //return the SearchResults to the view
            return PartialView("AddCategory", model);
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting error on SurfaceController when inserting or updating record.
How to resolve above issue. let me know what is the problem with code.

Comment: You haven't actually posted any code that show's how you are writing your records. Your repository is really the only code that is of any interest because it is this that is throwing the error.

Comment: I think, its throwing an error because of RenderModel.
I have used BaseModel which inherits RenderModel and error is of IPublishedContent which is passed to RenderModel.

I have updated my question and I have posted all code with BaseModel  & CategoryRepository.

Comment: You need to step through with the debugger and see where the exception is thrown. Your question description does state "I am getting an error when inserting record in database" which suggests that if you took the `repo.Insert(model);` and `repo.Update(model);` lines out then the page would not throw an exception. Otherwise we really need to see your repository code.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have used SurfaceController for post & ChildActionOnly for render listing on load and removed RenderModel from model. Now its working fine for CURD operation.